# Finding a definite integral using complex analysis.

Tags: contour-integration

Now, I want to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos (2x) -1}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x$, now I attempted to set $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{i2z}-1}{z^2}$ and then integrate around a similar contour to the classical one used for $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ i.e. a semicircle with a smaller semicircle cut out around 0. The difficulty I'm having is the -1 term, I can't get the contour integrals into the right form to use to evaluate the real integral. Anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Dear David, one question what do you then set the complex function as? $e^{iz^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating $f(z)=(e^{2iz}-1)/z^2$ along the real axis from $\rho$ to $R$ gives
$$J_1=\int_\rho^R\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx\ .$$
Integrating from $-R$ to $-\rho$ gives
$$J_3=-\int_R^\rho \frac{e^{-2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx
  =\int_\rho^R\frac{e^{-2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx\ .$$
Along the upper semicircle from $R$ to $-R$ we have
$$|e^{2iz}|=|e^{2i(x+iy)}|=e^{-2y}\le1$$
and so
$$|J_2|\le\pi R \frac{1+1}{R^2}$$
which tends to $0$ as $R\to\infty$.  Since $f$ has a simple pole at the origin, we have for the integral along the small semicircle
$$\lim_{\rho\to0}J_4=-\pi i{\rm Res}\bigl(f(z),z=0\bigr)=2\pi\ .$$
Since $f$ has no singularities inside the contour we have
$$J_1+J_2+J_3+J_4=0\ ,$$
and taking $R\to\infty$ and $\rho\to0$ gives
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{x^2}+\frac{e^{-2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx+2\pi=0\ .$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos 2x-1}{x^2}\,dx=-\pi\ .$$